# Can. we condense multiple related loops?

Tags: rust

Just a newbie learning Rust here.

When you have multiple loops like in this example. Is there an easy/idiomatic rust way to combine them all into a single loop? or perhaps just a smarter way to do this?

Link to playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d4893a0688a1ccb9fb4fc1c684dfe38

Code

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum USCoin {
    Penny,
    Nickel,
    Dime,
    Quarter,
    HalfDollar
}

fn make_change(mut value: f64) -> Vec<USCoin> {
    let mut change: Vec<USCoin> = vec![];
    while value >= 0.50 && value > 0.25 {
        change.push(USCoin::HalfDollar);
        value = value - 0.50;
    }
    
    while value >= 0.25 && value > 0.10 {
        change.push(USCoin::Quarter);
        value = value - 0.25;
    }
    
    while value >= 0.10 && value > 0.05 {
        change.push(USCoin::Dime);
        value = value - 0.10;
    }
    while value >= 0.05 && value > 0.01 {
        change.push(USCoin::Nickel);
        value = value - 0.05;
    }
    while value >= 0.01 && value != 0.0{
        change.push(USCoin::Penny);
        value = value - 0.01;
    }
    
    return change;
}

fn main() {
    let change: Vec<USCoin> = make_change(2.43);
    println!("{:?}", change);
}
```

Comment: Given that this is working code and you're looking for improvements (an admirable goal), you may have better luck on [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is a site built for that exact purpose.

Comment: Note that your tests are redundant: `value >= 0.50 && value > 0.25` is equivalent to just `value >= 0.50`

Comment: Obligatory warning: **Never use floating point numbers for counting money**

Comment: I learned that quickly through this... I ended up using using values like “134” then dividing by 100 to get 1.34. Very good advisable warning Krish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to avoid copy-pasted loops, by using `match` inside a loop.

```rust
fn make_change(mut value: f64) -> Vec<USCoin> {
    use USCoin::*;
    let mut change: Vec<USCoin> = vec![];
    while value > 0.001 {
        let (coin, coin_value) = match value {
            _ if value >= 0.50 => (HalfDollar, 0.50),
            _ if value >= 0.25 => (Quarter, 0.25),
            _ if value >= 0.10 => (Dime, 0.10),
            _ if value >= 0.05 => (Nickel, 0.05),
            _ if value >= 0.01 => (Penny, 0.01),
            _ => unreachable!(),
        };
        change.push(coin);
        value -= coin_value;
    }
    change
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What does the underscore in front of the if mean in the match statement mean?

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain it means "ignore the matched value". https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html